# Split an array in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I have a list of names with scores in lstInput (a listbox) that looks something like this:

```
Name1,100,200,300
Name2,100,200,300
Name3,100,200,300
```

...etc...

I need to split the array into a string and print the results of the person's name  and the scores that are separated by a comma.

What I have so far is the following:

```
For s As Integer = 0 To lstInput.Items.Count - 1
    lstOutput.Items.Add(lstInput.Items(s))
Next
```

Now, that displays the entire list, but I need to split the list into strings so that they display on their own: e.g. 
Name1
100
200
300

...etc..

Comment: Use [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)?

Comment: Yes, but it splits the first comma, so how do I make it split each one? I know I have to use a loop, but what about the next comma? If someone could post an example, that would help!

Comment: `String.Split` splits the whole line, not just the first word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For s As Integer = 0 To lstInput.Items.Count - 1
    dim items As String() = lstInput.Items(s).Split(",".ToCharArray()) 'splits into array of 4 elements

    dim name As String = items(0) 'first element is name
    dim score1 As String = items(1) 'second element is first score

    -- now do the rest yourself

    -- listOutput.Items.Add( concatenate name and the scores here)
Next
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It says Option Strict On disallows late binding. Any idea? *I am not turning off Option Strict on.

Comment: on which line is that, I didn't get that error even after turning option strict on?

Comment: I have added `.ToCharArray()` to the Split. That may cause it

Comment: Just a guess: maybe you need to `CType(lstInput.Items(s), String)`?

Comment: BTW, you can use `","c` instead of `",".ToCharArray()`.

Comment: @Neolisk Yes. There are several options. Am C#, and we don't do this in C#. Why in VB?

Comment: Because OP is asking about VB. :)

Comment: No, that's not my point. Why use `","c` when in C# you just use `.Split(',')`?

Comment: It still says it  doesn't allow late binding even though I used `.ToCharArray()`.

Comment: As suggested by @Neolisk, you can use `","c` instead of `",".ToCharArray()`. If that didn't solve it, then try his answer

Comment: @codingbiz: I got your point now. VB.NET does not have single quotes to escape char literals, so "X"c is how you do it.

Answer (score 2):

I may be going crazy, but I think the OP wants something like this:

```
For s As Integer = 0 To lstInput.Items.Count - 1
  lstOutput.Items.Add(String.Join(" ", CType(lstInput.Items(s), String).Split(",")))
Next
```

Purpose of this code is unknown but it ultimately removes commas, so this `Name1,100,200,300` becomes this `Name1 100 200 300` (just following the question). Guess I could have done `String.Replace` instead, but it's not as cool.